# How do I know which transactions run first

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

INSERT INTO Students VALUES(’Jason’,50);

UPDATE Students SET mark = mark + 10;

COMMIT
```

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ COMMITED

INSERT INTO Students VALUES (’Kylie’,70);

SELECT SUM(mark) FROM Students;

COMMIT
```

If I have two transactions that run simultaneously, how do I know what runs first and what values would be returned by the query? I understand that Serializable isolates T1. But more than that I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

if you run both at same time, `READ COMMITTED` will wait for `SERIALIZABLE` to finish. btw, seems `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is missing on your `TSQL`.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO Students VALUES(’Jason’,50);
   UPDATE Students SET mark = mark + 10;
COMMIT TRANSACTION

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ COMMITTED
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO Students VALUES (’Kylie’,70);
   SELECT SUM(mark) FROM Students;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```